# How can I use Unity AR without cloud services?

Tags: unity, augmented-reality

From what I've read so far, it looks like if I want to build AR apps with Unity, I need to use some kind of cloud service.

Is there a way to use AR without sharing my (and my users) data to some 3rd party? If so, how do I do this?

Comment: I've tried to clarify the single question here. Please feel free to edit or revert if I've misunderstood your intention. It would also be useful to include in the question the source you're consulting that says you need to use cloud services — this can give users who aren't as familiar with your situation more context so they can better help you.

Comment: Thank you its exactly what i mean.